# Applescript droplet that executes shell script

Tags: binary, applescript, automator, upx

I'd like to make an Applescript droplet with Automator that does the following: when I drop "Application.app" in the droplet, the script runs

```
./upx.out -d [the binary contained in the MacOS subfolder of Application.app]
```

where "Application.app" and the binary are variables, and where upx.out is contained in the Resources subfolder of the Automator droplet.

Answer (score 0):

```
on open myItem
    set pathtobinary to [you'll need to figure out how to get the path to the binary inserted here as a function of myItem]
    do shell script "./upx.out -d " & quoted form of pathtobinary
end open
```

Then save the script as an application.